# How to get a value for dynamic object's child

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and i am calling some power-shell scripts inside my web application, and populate a dynamic object with the powershell scripts results.. here is part of the results i get from running powershell scripts :-

[image]

can anyone adivce how i can access for example the BaseObject.Build value? i tried the following `results[0].BaseObject.Build` but i got a null reference exception . as `results[0].BaseObject` will be null! can anyone adivce on this please ?

Comment: What do you see in the intellisense when you do `results[0].` I would imagine you would see a `Build` property. try `results[0].Build.ToString()` If you could create a https://dotnetfiddle.net/ it would help.

Comment: @mwilson the intellisense will not show any thing as this is a dynamic object (build at runtime),, so i assume the intellisense will not be able to know any thing about it in advance is this correct ?

Comment: @mwilson now i wrote the following results[0].Build and it worked well on our Live environment which have Windows Server 2008 r2 + IIS-8 ,, while on our Dev environment which have Windows Server 2008 R" +IIS-7 i need to reference it using results[0].BaseObject.Build ... not sure why ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
   return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

call this method by GetPropValue(results[0], "Build")

it will returns Build value

for more information return to this post [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get BaseObject with reflection, like:

`results2.GetType().GetProperty("BaseObject").GetValue(results2, null)`

or

`results2.GetType().GetField("BaseObject").GetValue(results2, null)` .